# My request is returning nothing, how do I get the expected value?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

What I am trying to do is make a request from a website to gain stats of a user. However, when I run the code I have it is for some reason just giving me nothing.

```
 r = requests.get("https://r6.tracker.network/profile/xbox/tbzq")
 userPage = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
 kd = userPage.find(class_="trn-defstat__value")
 print(kd.text)
```

This is the code I am trying to use however, it quite literally returns nothing.

How do I go about getting the value I want which is `0.57` Attempting `find_all()` just raises an error so how do I go about this?

Comment: The `find` API finds the FIRST such div.  The first `trn-defstat__value` contains no text, just images.  You either need to use `find_all` and scroll through them, or search by the `data-stat` attribute.  `userPage.find_all('div', class_='trn-defstat__value')` certainly works.

Answer (score 1):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://r6.tracker.network/profile/xbox/tbzq"

try:
    response = requests.get(url)
    response.raise_for_status()  # Check for any request errors

    user_page = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    kd = user_page.find(class_="trn-defstat__value")

    if kd is not None:
        print(kd.text)
    else:
        print("KD element not found on the page.")

except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
    print("Error occurred during the request:", e)
```

By adding error handling and checking for request errors, you can identify any issues that may arise during the request. Additionally, the code includes a check to verify if the KD element was found on the page.

Answer (score 0):

You can search for an additional attribute to narrow down the search

```
attrs={'data-stat':'PVPKDRatio'}
```

e.g.

```
>>> userPage.find(class_="trn-defstat__value", attrs={'data-stat':'PVPKDRatio'})
<div class="trn-defstat__value" data-stat="PVPKDRatio">
0.57
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the variable 'kd' has no text so update your code to this:

```
r = requests.get("https://r6.tracker.network/profile/xbox/tbzq")
userPage = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
kd = userPage.find(class_="trn-defstat__value")
print(kd)
```

the last line is updated

but if you are trying to find a specific element not just all elements in this class, then you should search not just by class but also by data-stat, I'm using data-stat because in the component your looking for, that is the attribute they used,

```
<div data-stat="PVPKDRatio" class="trn-defstat__value">
0.57
</div>
```

anyways, here would be the code for that:

```
r = requests.get("https://r6.tracker.network/profile/xbox/tbzq")
userPage = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

kd = userPage.find('div', {'data-stat' : 'PVPKDRatio'})
print(kd)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please let me know if this works!

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
r = requests.get("https://r6.tracker.network/profile/xbox/tbzq")
#To get the content of a request, use r.content.
userPage = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
#Since there are too many divs with the class "trn-defstat__value", use data-stat.
kd = userPage.find("div", {"data-stat": "PVPKDRatio"})
#To get the innerHTML of an element, use str(element.encode_cotnents()). Then trim some uneccesary characters off each end.
print(str(kd.encode_contents())[4:][:-3])
```

Comment: I didn't see before, but my answer seems to be similar to @Anthony Kercher's answer, https://stackoverflow.com/a/76634183/19629009.

Answer (score 0):

In principle there may be many div elements with a data-stat attribute equal to PVPKDRatio and non-empty text.

So let's check all of them:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

with requests.get('https://r6.tracker.network/profile/xbox/tbzq') as response:
    response.raise_for_status()
    soup = BS(response.text, 'lxml')
    for item in soup.find_all('div', {'data-stat': 'PVPKDRatio'}):
        if (s := item.getText().strip()):
            print(s)
```

**Output:**

```
0.57
```